# Transaction log growing despite regular transaction log backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

I'm facing a popular issue, i'm afraid : my transaction log is growing and growing again on SQL SERVER. But I can't find the answers on the web.

I have a daily full backup, differential backup every hour and transaction log every 15 minutes. And they work fine, but what about that ldf file ? Is up to 100Go in 2-3 month, my database is about 15Go.

I perform some maintenance task the weekend : index rebuilding or reorganization if the fragmentation is below 30%. Plus i'm running a recompute of my small datawarehouse (15 millions rows). There is some task every night but nothing that big.

But, i dont know, why my transaction log is not truncate after the log backup ?

When I check the use of the LDF file, only 1.7% is used when I write this post.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.
Sorry for my poor english by the way...

EDIT : I have 119 VLF file and no one is used.

Answer (score 0):

truncation does not reduce the size of a physical log file. Reducing the physical size of a log file requires shrinking the file.
The size grow up, for example, because of long running transaction that are not removed during transaction log backup.

Regards
Giova

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mmmh, all right. I read many times that it was a bad practice to shrink my LDF, due to the potentially excessive fragmentation... So, should I do it ?

Comment: No, you don't have to do it if you don't need for more free space

Comment: I've a lot of free space :) but my boss is asking how much space is used by a database (to know how many DB we can put on one server i guess...).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to shrink your log files regularly. Seeing as how you have a backup strategy including `FULL`,`DIFFERENTIAL` and `TRANSACTION LOG` backups, you will do well to have a SQL job run on a schedule to shrink the log file in question to a bare minimum. I run a stored proc. with the shrink command regularly to

[DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493(v=sql.105).aspx) helps you shrink your log files to a set size.

`DBCC SHRINKFILE (DBNAME_Log, 1);` will shrink it down to 1MB for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

As i said below, I thought it was a bad practice to shrink my LDF, due to the potentially excessive fragmentation, have you heard about that ?

Comment: I suppose that point might be irrelevant based on your recent comment. When you're planning for a DB deployment, its better you take into account log file growth too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Sever Studio. Click right mouse button on selected database, then **Reports > Disk Usage**. You will see (internal) use of database and transaction logs files. Shrinking transaction log does not make any sense if you understand that maintenance task (like index rebuilding) needs a lot of space in transaction log. Rule of thumb - transaction log file is as big as largest table (**Reports > Disk Usage by Top Tables**)